# Use different background colors for uib progressbar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use the [progressbar](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar) from **ui-bootstrap** in two places in my template. I want them to completely have different colors though, including their background.

What I thought would be the easiest solution was to have two progressbars stacked in such a way as to create the effect. This unfortunately is quite obvious and especially in the corners.

```
<uib-progress class="progress-md">
    uib-bar value="level" type="skill"></uib-bar>
    <uib-bar value="100-level" type="skill-bg"></uib-bar>
</uib-progress>
```

[image]

Of course I dont want to edit ui-bootstraps code directly so I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the stacked example of the ui-bootstrap plunker will help.
Check it out on the ui-bootstrap example page.